# How to display web app running on an AWS Lightsail GitLab CE Linux instance in local browser

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ip-address, amazon-lightsail

I have a Flask web app in my AWS Lightsail GitLab CE Linux instance that I want to display on my local browser (in order to check how the UI looks). I've tried entering the given public IP address with the port numbers specified in the firewall rules, but they all time out. Can anyone tell me how to do this?